# Chave Estrangeira entre bancos de dados diferentes

Tags: laravel, postgresql

É possível fazer a ligação entre dois bancos de dados diferentes em uma Migration? Estou usando Postgres.

O que eu tenho:

```
$table->integer('id_cliente_produto')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('id_cliente_produto')->references('id_cliente_produto')->on('clienteproduto');
```

Preciso de algo como:

```
$table->integer('id_cliente_produto')->unsigned();
$table>foreign('id_cliente_produto')>references('id_cliente_produto')->on('Banco2.tabela');
```

Comment: Esses bancos de dados diferentes estão em servidores diferentes?

Comment: exatamente, estão mesmo em servidores diferentes.

Comment: Fora do framework é possível fazer isso no Postgres ?

Comment: Sim, usando db_link.

Comment: É impossível definir uma FOREIGN KEY entre tabelas de diferentes bancos de dados no PostgreSQL, contudo você pode defini-la entre tabelas de diferentes schemas do mesmo banco de dados. Com o db-link, ou mesmo um Foreign Data Wrapper, você pode acessar uma tabela de outro banco de dados mas não poderá criar uma restrição de integridade entre elas.

Comment: Dblink e trigger , fiz assim no Oracle

Answer (score 0):

Nunca precisei fazer isso, mas dando uma procurada no google encontrei esta solução (não testei para ver se funciona mesmo):

```
$table>foreign('id_cliente_produto')>references('id_cliente_produto')->on(new Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression('Banco2.tabela'));
```

Recomendação: coloque a referência para o nome do banco em algum arquivo de configuração, para caso o nome do banco mudar, bastará você alterar somente um arquivo.

Answer (score 0):

Para utilizar dois bancos de dados diferentes em um mesmo projeto laravel e que seja possível a relação entre eles faça o seguinte:

1 - Em seu arquivo .env coloque suas variaveis do novo banco

```
DB_ANOTHER_HOST=localhost
DB_ANOTHER_DATABASE=banco2
DB_ANOTHER_USERNAME=root
DB_ANOTHER_PASSWORD=
```

2 - Agora em seu config/database.php adicione esta conexão:

```
'banco2' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_ANOTHER_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_ANOTHER_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username'  => env('DB_ANOTHER_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password'  => env('DB_ANOTHER_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
            'engine'    => null,
        ],
```

3 - Por último em seu arquivo de entidade utilize esta nova conexão:

```
class Cadastro extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'banco2';
}
```

4 - Assim o modelo Cadastro estará no banco2 e todo meu sistema poderá responder pelo banco padrão.

5 - Por último mas não menos importante, não utilize sua coluna no banco principal como chave estrangeira, evite utilizar chaves estrangeiras, este é um exemplo, sempre no seu model faça a relação:

```
public function Enderecos() {
   return $this->hasMany(Cadastro:class, 'id', 'cadastro_id');
}
```

Comment: A resposta está Ok para relacionar pelo Eloquent, que cuidará de mapear as ligações, mas a questão era sobre Migration - criação da estrutura do banco de dados, ou seja, criação de integridade referencial por meio de chaves estrangeiras entre diferentes bancos de dados com PostgreSQL.